# Convert TLV to PHP array

Tags: php, parsing, tlv

I have a *Type Length Value* string:

```
a:4:{s:5:"value";s:4:"0.00";s:4:"type";N;s:12:"discounttype";s:10:"Percentage";s:13:"configoptions";N;}
```

Is it possible to convert it to `PHP array` or `JSON string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of string could be done with [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function. Also there is an article about that solving your needs [here](http://oss.tiggerswelt.net/oscar/tlv.php).

After it has been `unserialized`, it is an array. You can then convert using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

If you need extra help, write a comment